# I am trying to build a particular layout in flutter, can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout

I am trying to build this layout, Wrap seems to be a good option to align the sub-containers inside the parent container, bit I need to lazily load the sub-containers, so I go for ListView.builder(Layout 2), unfortunately ListView does not have wrap's property of ordering children as they reach the border of the parent container, reason being ListView is scrollable and does not provide the overflow error, which is needed to activate the wrap widget.

Can anyone suggest me a proper way to lazily load these sub container and to place them in proper order as seen in layout 1.

[image: Layout 1]

[image: Layout 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use girdView.builder

it is something like this

```
GridView.builder(
                                  gridDelegate:
                                      SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                          childAspectRatio: 1,
                                          mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                                          crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                                          crossAxisCount: 3),
                                  itemCount: list.length,
                                  itemBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    return widget[index];
                                  },
                                )
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, GridView was just the widget I was looking for.